# Switch language in TFS 2017 Monaco editor during code review

Tags: tfs, monaco-editor

Code reviewing a PR in TFS 2017 lacks syntax highlighting for languages such as Groovy and Kotlin. Simply changing the display language would help a lot, eg coloring Kotlin files as Java.

If I'm correct, the editor in TFS is [Monaco Editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/) (there is a monaco editor element in the HTML), which seems capable of switching both language and theme, though these options are not exposed in TFS.

Is it possible to somehow change the syntax highlighting and theme in TFS PR view? Either through a TFS plugin or a hidden setting in the editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the TFS/VSTS web portal is just [using monaco-editor](https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/a-quick-look-at-the-new-visual-studio-online-quot-monaco-quot-code-editor)  a browser based code editor.

However, it's not able to switch language on the TFS server side for now. You could add a uservoice [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services), TFS PM will kindly review your suggestion.

As a workaround, you could copy your code in PR and review them in some other standalone application/editor which support syntax highlighting for languages such as Groovy or directly change the  display language locally.

*PS: [monaco-editor](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor) also has been made standalone.*

Comment: There are already a lot of syntax highlighting requests there, a lot overlapping and a lot 'archived', and I voted for  a few. Eg [this](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/7540519-add-customizing-syntax-highlighting) would help my use case.

Comment: @Love :( This is marked ARCHIVED  and  comment closed which may not capture by PM.

Comment: That is fair, your answer confirms it is the Monaco editor and informs on the state of things. Though I hope that the language can be changed in the near future. Copying the content to another editor is not practical

Comment: It seems [Monaco Editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/) have kotlin support now, can we expect kotlin support in TFS/Azure devops soon?

Comment: @Love Thanks for your kindly sharing and update. Not pretty sure  about this. But if a new feature release, it should first in Azure DevOps Service. Then after several weeks, it may also add in the latest azure devops updated minor version. You could track sprint update in Azure DevOps Service here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-158-update If it's already in azure devOps Service. Then it should also support in TFS/Azure DevOps soon.